# SQL Flag across Partition on condition

Tags: sql, ssms, window-functions

I am attempting to create a flag, which populates 'Y' whenever the BD Line count reaches 4 for each Account. I've attached an output example.

I basically need to flag all rows when one value found in a group.

[image: Output]

Comment: do you really want to persist this denormalized column?  why not just query at runtime with a HAVING COUNT =4 type of clause?

Comment: I want to include all rows if the count reaches 4. When I use having, it only pull rows with Count =4

Comment: You should post your query, and your expected results.

Comment: So you don't care about persisting the flag? You just want to get all rows where the account grouping has a bd_line_count >= 4?

Comment: Yes - Think this gets it : case when Max(bd.BD_LINE_Count) over(partition by bd.Account)
  >= 4 then 'Yes' else 'No' end Flag

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't actually need to persist the flag (my impression from the comments), I think you are probably looking for something like:

```
SELECT test.*, CASE WHEN MAX(bd_line_count) OVER (PARTITION BY account) >= 4 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END flag
FROM test
```

This uses the analytic version of `MAX` to find the largest `bd_line_count` within the `account` grouping and sets a column `flag` based on that. You could then wrap that to get all the 'Y' rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT test.*, CASE WHEN MAX(bd_line_count) OVER (PARTITION BY account) >= 4 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END flag
  FROM test
) t
WHERE flag = 'Y'
```

However, if you're going to do that, there's no need to actually have a Y/N flag. You could just use the maximum directly:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT test.*, MAX(bd_line_count) OVER (PARTITION BY account) mx
  FROM test
) t
WHERE mx >= 4
```

You can see this (and a few other variations) [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mye_CmOL).

It's somewhat unclear if you are generating your line count or whether this is actually stored and could be different than counting the rows. Depending on the answers to that, you might prefer something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE account IN
(
 SELECT account
 FROM test
 GROUP BY account
 HAVING COUNT(*) >=4
)
```

The inner query `count`s the number of rows per `account` and finds the `account`s that have 4 or more. The outer query gets all of the rows that match those accounts.